# PL/SQL Package code is not visible inside oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I Have execute privilege on a PL/SQL Package , but when i try to open the declaration for it , the code is not shown , and the screen only shows :

```
create or replace
```

[image]

is that a missing privilege ?

Comment: Is it (the package) wrapped?

Comment: no it is not ...

Comment: Not sure if it is the same issue but have a read of the below.... seems to be same symptoms
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cant-view-procedurepackage-function-body-sqldeveloper-nelson-ateya/